# How to verify valid date and format, error for each

Tags: php, regex, date

I am using a date format `YYYY-MM-DD`. I am looking to check for proper format and date validity and echo an appropriate error message for each. My result is echoing an invalid date even when date is valid:

```
//validate date
if (!preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/',$date))   
{
    $dateErr = "Format must be \"YYYY-MM-DD\"" ;
}
if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/', $postedDate, $datebit)) 
{
    return checkdate($datebit[2] , $datebit[3] , $datebit[1]);
}
else    
{
    $dateErr = "Must be valid date." ;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to redo this function: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php ?

Comment: I think you mixing up with your vars.. the first time you use `$date`, the second time `$postedDate`

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to grab the values for use later anyway...

```
$YYYY=substr($date,0,4);
$DD=substr($date,7,2);
$MM=substr($date,5,2);
checkdate($MM,$DD,$YYYY);
```

if you are actually concerned about the format of the string for insertion into sql or something, you could filter it through date() or something

Comment: another alternative would be to explode date by "-", then use the array elements...  all sorts of options.